# How to create a View showing rows from splitted data

Tags: sql-server

With a table as:

```
Name    Num     Value
----------------------
Peter   10      10
Mary    10,15   5,10
John    5,20    10,20
```

How can I get a result as the follow table with a View ?

```
Name   Num   Value
------------------
Peter  10     10
Mary   10      5
Mary   15     10
John    5     10
John   20     20
```

Notice Mary and John have multiple data (comma-delimited).

I've a function to do the split of a cell and returns a table but just for a specific row and cell, hos to iterate from all table ?

Aditional Info:

```
SELECT NAM.NAME, Data AS NUM, VAL.VALUE
  FROM dbo.Split((SELECT NUM FROM t1 WHERE LineNum = 2), ','))
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Id As Id1, Data AS VALUE
          FROM dbo.Split((SELECT VALUE FROM t1 WHERE LineNum = 2), ','))
    ) AS VAL
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT NAME FROM t1 WHERE LineNum = 2
    ) AS NAM
WHERE Id = Id1
```

Note: LineNum is row number from t1

From Second Row of t1 (Mary | 10,15 | 5,10)

Previous Function returns table as:

```
Name   Num   Value
------------------
Mary    10    5
Mary    15   10
```

Split Function from a cell (10,15) returns:

```
Id   Data
-----------
1    10
2    15
```

===============================================

My Split Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
```

Comment: How about you show us your split function? Depending on the splitter you are using this may not be possible. Of course this also begs the question...can you change your system and stop storing delimited values like this? It is truly an awful way to handle data.

Comment: Hi, I have no way to change the original data (delimited values cells)

Comment: But where is your split function? That is the part that is potentially going to make this not work. You will need the ordinal position of each element so you can ensure that each num and value are matched up correctly.

Comment: My Split function:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Name varchar(50), Num varchar(50), Value  varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
('Peter','10',  '10'),
('Mary','10,15','5,10'),
('John','5,20', '10,20')

Select A.Name
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select Num   = A.RetVal
                      ,Value = B.RetVal
                From (
                        Select  RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                               ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(A.Num,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                ) A
                Join (
                        Select  RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                               ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(A.Value,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                ) B on A.RetSeq=B.RetSeq
             ) B
```

Returns

```
Name    Num Value
Peter   10  10
Mary    10  5
Mary    15  10
John    5   10
John    20  20
```

> **Edit - Another option with a UDF**

```
Select A.Name
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select Num   = A.RetVal
                      ,Value = B.RetVal
                From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.Num,',') A
                Join [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.Value,',') B 
                  on A.RetSeq=B.RetSeq
             ) B
```

The fastest UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = Substring(@String, A.N, A.L) 
    From   cte4 A
);
--Much faster than str-Parse, but limited to 8K
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to do the work.   Now I have to study it and all the xml use I didn't know.

Comment: @P.A If interested, there is a faster parser function.  Just wasn't clear if you wanted a UDF

Comment: Sean, here is my SPlit Function:

Comment: Thanks John, the one with the UDF is perfect and simple to me.

Comment: @P.A Happy to help